# Parse Json Array in KQL

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, kql, kusto-explorer

Json text isn't parsing in KQL correctly. I tried using parse_json as well but that didn't work either. I did confirm the extend AllProperties is holding the correct data.

```
DeviceInfo
| where RegistryDeviceTag == "Standard"
| extend AllProperties = todynamic(LoggedOnUsers)
| project DeviceName, Users = AllProperties["Username"]
```

Output gives me the correct DeviceName but doesn't give any data in the Username field.

Comment: It may help it you would provide a sample value or 2 that aren't being parsed according to your expectations

Comment: Yes. So in LoggedOnUsers you're getting this output:  [{"UserName":"TheUserName","DomainName":"TheDomainName","Sid":"TheSID#"}]. I'm only looking to split Username into it's own column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(based on the sample input you provided in the comment)*

if the array that is "LoggedOnUsers" includes exactly one entry, you can do this:

```
print input = '[{"UserName":"TheUserName","DomainName":"TheDomainName","Sid":"TheSID#"}]'
| project UserName = parse_json(input)[0].UserName
```

otherwise, you can use `mv-expand` or `mv-apply`:

```
print input = '[{"UserName":"TheUserName","DomainName":"TheDomainName","Sid":"TheSID#"}]'
| project parse_json(input)
| mv-apply input on (
    project UserName = input.UserName
)
```